# Django admin custom queryset from UI

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible with django to add a custom html select to an admin page in order to modify the queryset of a specific model?

For example, I have a "Product" model and inside the Products admin page I get all the product.

I would like to have an html select in that page so that the admin can change the queryset not to show ALL the products but just part of it

Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you want them to see less products? Filtering by a boolean field? Searching on a text/character field?

Comment: lookup how to do SimpleListFilters to add custom filters to an admin model.